# Can't fetch Notes(Data) from Api using user_id

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to fetch notes data from the api using user_id, but I am not able to hit the api i tried logging but can't fetch data from api . Can anyone hep me what i am missing in code
Console Check Error I am getting 404 error while fetching data.
Status : Not Found
message: "Http failure response for http:

```
    refresh(user_id){
    this.isLoadingResults = true;
    this.api.getdatachoice(user_id).subscribe(data =>{
      this.studentData = data['items'];
      console.log('studentData', this.studentData);
      
      this.isLoadingResults = false;
    })
    this.filterInput
      .valueChanges
      .debounceTime(200)
      .subscribe(term => {
      this.filterText = term;
    });

  }
```

```
      getdatachoice(user_id : any){
      try{
      const requestUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/api/admin/adminDashboard/getchoice=`+user_id;
        return this.httpClient.get(requestUrl);
      }catch(error){
        this.handleError("getdatachoice : "+JSON.stringify(error));
      }
      }
```

```
    router.get('/adminDashboard/getchoice', function (req, res) {
    var students = [];
    var course_name;
     console.log("----------------------------fetched-------------------------------------");
    //  models.User.findById(req.user._id({
    models.User.find({
        where:{
         userId : req.query.user_id,
            id : req.body.user_id
        }
    }).models.Application.getUnsignedUser(req.body.user_id).then(data => {
        require('async').eachSeries(data, function(student, callback){

            var courieraddress;
            if(student.isNewAddressSame == true || student.isNewAddressSame == "" || 
      student.isNewAddressSame == null){
                courieraddress = student.address;
            }else{
                courieraddress = student.newaddress
            }
      //   models.User_Transcript.getCollegeName(student.user_id).then(function(colleges){
               // 
          models.Institution_details.getAllInstitutionType(student.user_id).then(function(types){
                models.Applicant_Educational_Details.getCourseName(student.user_id).then(function 
            name(edu_details) {
                    if(edu_details.length > 0){
                        course_name = edu_details ? edu_details[0].Course_full_name : '';
                        //console.log("course_name---->"+course_name);
                    }else{
                        course_name = '';
                    }
                    students.push({
                        id : student.id,
                        name :student.name,
                        email : student.email,
                        user_id : student.user_id,
                        university_name: student.university,
                        transcript_name: student.tcname,
                       student.instruction_medium : '--' ,
                        application_date : moment(new 
                        Date(student.created_at)).format("DD/MM/YYYY"),
                        recepientsname :student.name,
                        courieraddress : courieraddress,
                        noOfCopies : student.numofcouriers,
                        couremail : student.couremail,
                        courmobile :  student.courmobile,
                        newemail : student.newemail,
                        studentsAction : (student.preferredoptionfortranscriptdownload) ? 
                        student.preferredoptionfortranscriptdownload : 'Email',
                        course_name : course_name,
                        notes : student.notes , 
                        education_lock : student.education_lock ? student.education_lock : 'true',
                        course_short_form :edu_details[0] ? edu_details[0].CourseName : '',
                        enrollmentYear : student.enrollmentYear,
                        enrollmentYearStandard : student.enrollmentYearStandard,
                        leavingYear : student.leavingYear,
                        leavingYearStandard : student.leavingYearStandard

                    });
                    callback();
                });
               // });
           // });
        }, function(){
            res.json({
                status: 200,
                message: 'Student retrive successfully',
                items : students,
                total_count : students.length
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It would be good if you could reduce your code to the smallest amount possible to show the problem. For example, just have your endpoint return a "hello world" response. Then it would be easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are making a request to `/api/admin/adminDashboard/getchoice=<id>` but your router is pointing to `/adminDashboard/getchoice`. You need to make them the same.